# Is SchemaCrawler broken when using its API?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, schemacrawler

I am refering the doc in http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/how-to.html#api
But I never get what I want. The tables returned is always empty.

```
final Connection connection = ... // Get a MYSQL connection;
final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.maximum());
options.setTableInclusionRule(new IncludeAll());
options.setTableNamePattern("*");

final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options);

for (final Schema schema: catalog.getSchemas())
{
    Collection<Table> tables = catalog.getTables(schema);
    // 
    // The size of tables is always 0
    // 
    System.out.println(tables);
}
```

Comment: MySQL has no schemas, only catalogs (in JDBC terms). You should use `getCatalogs()` not `getSchemas()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set the table name pattern, so please remove the following line:

`options.setTableNamePattern("*");`

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: Thanks Sualeh, that really helps